# C# UDP messages from PLC can not be received in Unity3D, but is visible in Wireshark

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp, wireshark

I have a PLC directly connected via an Ethernet cable to a Win10 Laptop, running Unity3d. My goal is to send data from the PLC to the Unity model using a UDP connection.

Currently the PLC is sending messages every second and they are visible in Wireshark.

The Unity half has a Receive-Thread running. It is able to receive via the local 127.0.0.1 IP-connection. I also have a sender implemented in Unity to test that and it works as expected.

What does not work, is to receive messages from the PLC directed to the same port as the internal connection.

So far I...

- ... set the ethernet port to a static IP (192.168.0.41)
- ... opened the ports for UDP communication in the firewall, that should not be the problem.
- ... changed the receiving port (currently set to 8052)
- ... tried variations of the client set-up, nothing changed.
- ... researched and digged through diverse threads and comment sections without success. Though I have found that other people encountered the same problem, nobody posted an answer.

Unity3d C# Receive Code (shortened to relevant parts):

```
private void init()
{
   port = 8052;

        receiveThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();
    }

    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        // create a client
        client = new UdpClient(port);
        while (true)
        {
            // if an Error occours the program doesn't crash
            try
            {
                // Create connection point and receiving client + receiving bytes
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                print("Number of bytes: " + data.Length.ToString());

                /*
                 * use the received data
                 */

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Output if receiving experienced an error
                print(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I think could be the problem:

- There is another layer that can block the connection next to the firewall that I did not consider yet
- The client setup needs to be different to receive messages from external sources.
- An asychron UDP client is needed

The (receive) code is based on:
[Simple UDP implementation](https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c.15900/).

Additional question, since I am quite new to networking: If Wireshark can see the package, shouldn't it already be past the firewall and other possible blocking layers? Or is Wireshark looking on an even lower communication layer?

Thank you in advance!

Screenshots from Wireshark:
[Multiple incoming messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CRCI.png)
[Details of one message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCkHy.png)

Comment: What PLC? What does the sending side look like? Are you sure it is UDP?

Comment: Most likely an IP configuration issue (what´s the IP of the PLC and of your PC?). Wireshark can "see" whatever reaches the network card, your receive code will onlçy see whatever the protocol layer passes on after being passed through firewalls.

Comment: An CPU315-2 PN/DP, and yes, I adapted the Siemens [template for UPD communication](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/29738463/how-do-you-program-the-communication-blocks-fb67-tusend-fb68-turcv-fb65-tcon-and-fb66-tdiscon-in-order-to-use-the-udp-protocol-for-data-exchange-via-the-integrated-profinet-interface-of-an-s7-300-s7-400-cpu-?dti=0&lc=en-WW) for my purposes. Also Wireshark is set up to only show UDP connections

Comment: IP of the PLC is 192.168.0.1 and the (PC) ethernet port has the mentioned 192.168.0.41

Comment: With your program running (assuming Windows), open a command prompt and type `netstat -aon`.  This will list all TCP and UDP ports that are listening on your system, along with their PID.  Look for UDP 8052, then check it's listening on `0.0.0.0` and has your program's PID.  Might be helpful to post a screenshot of any UDP 8052 entries you find.

Comment: Can you put screenshot of the Wireshack data you captured?

Comment: @Trevor I ran `netstat -aon` and couldn't find any 8052 connections... the unity window freezes when it is not the active window, that could be a reason or that the connection is not created?

@Programmer I attached screenshots in the main question, bottom line

Comment: That's suspicious.  Having just run `var client = new UdpClient(8052);` on my test project, `netstat` then shows `UDP  0.0.0.0:8052  *:*  21488` representing process ID 21488 listening on any local IP address on UDP port 8052, for packets from anywhere.  If you aren't seeing that, then I guess it could be being blocked from listening by a local firewall, or possibly something is happening so that the receive thread is exiting before you get chance to see it in `netstat`.  Can you check the thread is still alive?

Comment: The thread is continiously returing `true` for being alive in the Unity console. I just checked the number generators in the Unity send script and they freeze as well when the window is not active. Maybe it is really Unity pausing all actions when it is not the active window.

Comment: Sorry. I was not notified for your comment maybe that's because you use @ to address two people in one comment. Your CPU315-2 PN/DP device IP is 192.168.0.41? What type of message do expect to receive on your Unity side of the code? Are you connected to the-same network with this device?

Comment: @Programmer good to know about the @ issue, thanks!The CPU315-2 PN/DP has the 192.168.0.1 IP, the PC the 192.168.0.41. They are directly connected by Ethernet, no Switch or similar things in between. I am sending two floats (or REALs on the PLC side)

Comment: Do you have a router laying around? Can you connect both with a router instead of connecting them directly? This will help eliminate where the possible issue is.

Comment: @Programmer No, unfortunately not. But I also do not suspect the error on the PLC side, since other communication like the programming and live-logging works via the Ethernet connection. I can also ping the PLC from my PC without any problem.

Comment: @Trevor Sorry for the confusion, it seems like I was lacking some focus yesterday. I looked at the process ID as ports.
There is indeed a single UPD connection at `0.0.0.0.:8052 *|* 11300` but no other connection with the same port, neither TCP nor UDP

Comment: UPDATE about my research: Since I can ping the PLC I thought I should try to send values to the PLC. Using Wireshark I can see that the messages from Unity do not use the Ethernet Port but they go via my USB hub in direction router/ internet. When I disconnect the Hub I get a SocketException that the "operation was attempted to an unreachable network".

Now my theory is, that the socket / client is ignoring the ethernet port and is only listening & sending to the USB Hub since it is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a very frustrating journey I found a work-around that is not nice but does the job:

I wrote a python script that opens a socket, receives the external data and forwards it via the local IP to Unity. And that works.

Here is the code:

```
# Import libraies
import socket
import time

# Set send IP adress and port
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT_Rec = 8052
UDP_PORT_Unity = 8055

print("Receiving on Port:" + str(UDP_PORT_Rec))
print("Sending to IP:" + UDP_IP + ":" + str(UDP_PORT_Unity))

# Set socket to send udp messages and bind port
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('',UDP_PORT_Rec));

## Keep sending message from file location
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) #buffer size, hopefully no problem if too big
    print("Received")

    sock.sendto(data, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT_Unity))
    print("Send")
```

Tools that are useful for your trouble shooting:

- Install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)! It is probably the best tool out there to track Internet traffic. Packages that are visible in Wireshark might not be visible for a normal application!
- Use [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/) to generate and receive traffic. The application uses a basic approach to receive packages - If it can then your programm should be able to as well.
- Check with `netstat -aon` if your socket is running.
- For completion: Check your firewall settings.

Thanks to Trevor and Programmer for the help.

Comment: On the Unity Discord Network channel a user commented that the Unity Editor is only listening to the local host (127.0.0.1) and only the build project connects to external sources. That has proven to be correct for me - my connections do work in the build.